# Keras Multi-Class Image Segmentation - number of classes?

Tags: keras, deep-learning, image-segmentation, unet-neural-network

Apologies if this is a stupid question but I have a dataset with **two** classes I wish to attempt to classify using a U-Net.

When creating the label matrices, do I need to explicitly define the null / base class (everything which isn't a class) or will Keras calculate this automatically?

For example, if I have a set of images where I'd like to classify the regions where there is a **dog** or where this is a **cat**, do I need to create a third label matrix which labels everything which is **not a dog or cat** (and thus, have **three** classes)?

Furthermore, the null class dominates the images I'm wishing to segment; if I were to use a class_weight, it seems to only accept a dictionary as input whereas I swear before I good specify a list and that would suffice.

If I treat my problem as a two-class problem, I'm assuming I need to specify the weight of the null class too, i.e. `class_weight = [nullweight, dogweight, catweight]`.

Thank you

edit: Attached example
[image]

Is this above image a two class or three class problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must specify the other class since the network needs to differentiate between the dog, the cat and the background.

As for the `class_weights` parameter, the discussion is a little bit more complicated, you cannot assign like you would do in a simple classification problem.

Indeed, in many problems the background constitutes a big part of the image so you need to be careful when approaching such an imbalanced problem.

You need to inspect the parameter `sample_weights`, not `class_weights`, you can have a look at these threads:

1. https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/31129/sample-importance-training-weights-in-keras
2. https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/3653
3. [Weighting samples in multiclass image segmentation using keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60253082/weighting-samples-in-multiclass-)
   image-segmentation-using-keras

Comment: Thank you for the reply. So it's very straight forward to reframe the problem with the negative class and classes 1 and 2 (three classes total). These examples of weighting the problem so the background (negative class) is weighted less than the other classes seems quite complicated though

Comment: Yes, it is a little bit complicated. By the way, if my answer helped you in a way, I would appreciate if you upvoted it (not necessarily accepting the answer). It helps both me and you and others with the same question.